# The number of compares for an optimized merge-sort on an already sorted array

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I would like to know how I can calculate the number of compares for an optimized merge sort described below, on an array already sorted.

It is like an ordinary merge-sort but does not 'merge' if two subarrays are already sorted.

```
mergesort(arr, auxArr, lo, hi)
  if (hi <= lo) return;
  mid = lo + (hi + lo) / 2

  sort(arr, auxArr, lo, mid)
  sort(arr, auxArr, mid+1, hi)

  if (less(arr[mid], arr[mid+1]) return; // optimization
  merge(arr, auxArr, lo, mid ,hi)
```

Here is my attempt to find out the number of compares

1. Let C(N) be the number of compares
2. C(N) = 2 * C(N/2) + 1 (number of compares to sort two subarrays + 1 compare for our optimization)
3. Using recurrence relation,

---

```
C(N) = = 2 * C(N/2) + 1
= 2 ( 2C(N/4) + 1 ) + 1
= 4 C(N/4) + 1 + y
...
= N C(N/N) + 1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2^(log2 (N/2))
= 1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2^(log2 (N/2))
```

But the answer says it is ~ log2(N), and I am stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: What does the `sort` method do? Or are those supposed to be recursive calls to `mergesort`?

Comment: I think your `mid` calculation is off. If `lo=4` and `hi=5`, then `mid` ends up being `4 + (5+4)/2`. That would be 8. I think you want `mid= lo + (hi - lo)/2`. Or, even simpler, `(hi + lo)/2`. Try it with `lo=4` and `hi=7`. `mid` should be 5.

Comment: But assuming you get the midpoint calculation correct and those really are supposed to be recursive calls to `mergesort`, when N is a power of 2, the line that compares the middle two items will be executed N-1 times.

Comment: `1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2^(log2 (N/2))` is a geometric series. Can you proceed?

Comment: Your algorithm is `\Theta(n)` for sorted array and your expansion is true.

Comment: If the answer says `log2(N)` then the answer is wrong. It takes O(n) compares just to check if an array is already sorted.

Comment: Example case: if n is a power of 2, then it takes n-1 compares, which translates into O(n) compares, the same as checking to see if an array is already sorted. Say n = 16, then at the deepest level of recursion, there are 8 compares, then next level up, 4 compares, => 8 + 4 + 2 + 1 = 15 = 16 - 1 compares.